# Getting variable name of assigned object

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, variables

Is it possible to define a function like get_name(x), such that:

```
>>> a = A()
>>> get_name(a)
'a'
```

In other words the function returns the variable-string that an object is assigned to?

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: What if the object is assigned to multiple variables?

Comment: you may want to look up the globals() function. it is possible to do something similar to what you ask.